# jQuery ajax call data param issue in spring mvc environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to the jQuery and currently trying to implement an ajax call which will permanently poll the server and request some data. The ajax is working fine as i was able to hit my server side controller method however after adding a **data: gameLink** param it is stopped working. Here is my jQuery function:

```
window.setInterval(pollActiveParticipants, 10000);
    function pollActiveParticipants() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "pollActiveParticipants",
            data: {"gameLink": $gameLink },    //this is where i need help! 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    '<p>' + value.username + '</p><br>';
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
```

The $gameLink is present on the jsp as few lines below i am using it as

```
<br>
 Other participants can access the game on the following url: &nbsp; ${gameLink} 
<br>
```

What is the correct syntax to add the $gameLink as request param or what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: you are welcome. It avoids complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this?

```
function pollActiveParticipants() { 
 var gameLink = '${gameLink}';

 //Make sure it is having the value here.
 //alert(gameLink); or console.log(gameLink);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "pollActiveParticipants",
        data: {"gameLink": gameLink },   
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                '<p>' + value.username + '</p><br>';
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

or

```
var gameLink = '${gameLink}';    //previously '<%=gameLink %>', not recommended 
url: "pollActiveParticipants?gameLink="+gameLink,
dataType: 'json', 
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works fine. Why it needs to extract to a separate variable and using of the variable inside of the jquery? But yeah thanks for the answer.

Comment: It doesn't - did you try my answer below (posted first BTW)?

Comment: @nickdos - The part var gameLink = '${gameLink}';data: {"gameLink": gameLink }, is working fine for me and if I alert the gamelink it writes me the correct output. But yes as soon as i'll get a chance, i'll try what you suggested as it is quite elegant solution also. I appreciate both of you answers guys!

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab and guess `$gameLink` is a GSP var and not a JS var... In which case you need to string quote it thus:

```
data: {"gameLink": "${gameLink}" },
```